# mongoDB mongoose group by month and total sum

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this `orderdetails` model

```
const model = new Schema(
  {
    district: { type: String },
    category: String,
    producer: String,
    variety: String,
    qty: String,
    price: String,
    subtotal: String,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

I want to get the monthly sales report by `variety`.
First I filter the `variety` and then group it by the month and after calculating the sum of `qty`

This is my query

```
 const monthly = await OrderDetails.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          variety,
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            
            month: { $month: "$createdAt" },
            qty: { $sum: { $toInt: "$qty" } },
          },
        },
      },

      { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
      {
        $project: {
          qty: "$_id.qty",
          Month: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              [
                "",
                "Jan",
                "Feb",
                "Mar",
                "Apr",
                "May",
                "Jun",
                "Jul",
                "Aug",
                "Sep",
                "Oct",
                "Nov",
                "Dec",
              ],
              "$_id.month",
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

But the output comes like this

Output for this query is this

```
[
  { _id: { month: 4, qty: 1 }, qty: 1, Month: 'Apr' },
  { _id: { month: 4, qty: 5 }, qty: 5, Month: 'Apr' }
]
```

But the expected output is one record with a total qty is 6 like this

```
[
  { _id: { month: 4, qty: 6 }, qty: 6, Month: 'Apr' },
 
]
```

What's wrong in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since qty is for accumulator, change your `$group` from

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: { $month: "$createdAt" },
        qty: { $sum: { $toInt: "$qty" } }
      }
    }
  }
```

to

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { month: { $month: "$createdAt" } },
      qty: { $sum: { $toInt: "$qty" } }
    }
  }
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eC2zQGcRZKV)